# When i am trying to get excel export, Button_click do nothing ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

When i am trying to get excel export from my mysqldatabase, it doesnt do anything on button_click. I can see that gridview is filling by DataTable but on postback it doesnt download the excel output of my gridview.I cant find out that where is the problem. Thanks for helping guys.

**Here is my .aspx gridview code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
                    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="isbn" HeaderText="isbn" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="display_name" HeaderText="bookName" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="authorName" HeaderText="authorName" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                    </Columns>
```

**Here is my databind and button click**

```
private void BindGrid()
        {

            DataTable dt = book.getAllbookExcelExport();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void btnExport_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                this.BindGrid();

                GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

            }

        }
```

**Here is my page_load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

            ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btnSave);

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                this.BindGrid();

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't use UpdatePanels, does it work?

Comment: I solved it with redirecting another php file. There is a method in php to give excel output. I didnt realize what is problem.